# Event propagation in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-events

I've just the documentation on [the Qt event system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) and the [`QEvent` class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qevent.html).  I'm interested in the behavior of the [`QObject::event()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#event) method.  The documentation states:

> This virtual function receives events to an object and should return true if the event e was recognized and processed.

What is the expected behavior when `false` is returned from the `event()` method?  What else is attempted in order to handle the event?  Is the event automatically forwarded to the parent object?

**Note**: I know the source is available, and I do have a copy.  I'm ideally looking for some piece of documentation addressing this behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the best practice is to explicitly forward the events to the base-class event method if you do not wish to filter that event type (e.g. `return QObject::event(event);`) since the event function delegates events to specific handlers (e.g. `QWidget::keyPressEvent`).

[QCoreApplication::notify](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#notify) propogates events based on the return value. On `true`, it considers the event as consumed and stops. Otherwise, the event is passed to the object's parent. For more information, see [Events and Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) and [Another Look at Events](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html).

Comment: What does "propagates events based on the return value" mean?  This seems obvious at first, but where else does it propagate to?  There is only one receiver to the event.  How would it know what receiver to use instead?

Comment: This best practice is well documented in the cited links, but it doesn't answer the question.  Who uses this return value?

Comment: Look at the source code for QCoreApplication::notify. It uses the return value of QObject::event. Events are propagated to an object's parent if it has one.

Comment: It knows where to propagate the event because every object has a parent pointer.

Comment: Didn't notice that part.  It says "For certain types of events (e.g. mouse and key events), the event will be propagated to the receiver's parent and so on up to the top-level object if the receiver is not interested in the event (i.e., it returns false).".  Unfortunately, the documentation is not clear: it only applies for *certain type of events*, whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

Some Events can be propagated.Event will be propagated to it's parent and it's parent recursively until it is processed. Take a look at this:https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-events.html